# Find cartesian product of 2 collections

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I am trying to write a function in clojure returns cartesian product

```
(my-compute-fn [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
```

will return

```
[[1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [2 4] [2 5] ....]
```

My attempt resulted in this

```
(defn compute [col1 col2]
    (let [totcol2 (count col2)
          totcol1 (count col2)]
         (map #(vector %1 %2)
               (mapcat #(repeat totcol1 %1) col1)
               (take (* totcol1 totcol2) (cycle col2)))))
```

Which does the job, but looks a bit clunky.
What would be a better and more concise implementation, involving more readily available functions from clojure.core?

Thanks!

edit:
Found clojure combinatorics, and it doesn't seem there's a *magic functional way* of doing this.

Comment: How about the combinatorics' `cartesian-product`? :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure: How do I get a list of combinations of 'coordinates'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646544/clojure-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-combinations-of-coordinates)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`for` is the prime candidate for this task:

```
(for [a [1 2 3]
      b [4 5 6]]
  [a b])
;; => ([1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [2 4] [2 5] [2 6] [3 4] [3 5] [3 6])
```

You can supply `for` with any number of seqs and it will bind the given symbols to each element of the seq associated with them. There is even cooler stuff like `:when` that lets you e.g. find all those products whose sum is 7:

```
(for [a [1 2 3]
      b [4 5 6]
      :when (= (+ a b) 7)]
  [a b])
;; => ([1 6] [2 5] [3 4])
```

Comment: Seems quite elegant and simple! Thanks!